# How to forbid C# service from start under LocalSystem account?

Tags: c#, service, localhost

I need my service to run only under user account. What should I do to gain that? 
I've tried to check for Environment.UserName to check this. But it looks so that compiler does not compile this part of code to executable file.
Thanks for fast responses!

Comment: The compiler compiles all code apart from things with no side-effects that might be optimised away.  Property accesses are not included in that - the code is definitely there.  You could check Environment.UserName, what are you looking for in it?

Comment: Yes, problem definitely solved with this method. My mistake was that I didn't use case insensitive strings comparison. It is needed In OnStart() method to create the check of the name of user that started the application(service). If it fails - return from function, otherwise - continue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a *one-time* fix:

Once you install your service, goto Control Panel->Administrative tools->Services and components

there you need to configure the properties of your service.

Right click on your service, and choose properties - goto the Log on tab, and there you can set under which User the service will run.

good luck!

EDIT:

For a permanent fix - **ONLY IF** you're using a **VS Setup Project** to install your service:

- Double click on your installer's .CS file, a Design window will come up
- Now you're supposed to see an instance if your service (I think the default is ServiceProcessInstaller)
- Right click it, choose properties
- Under **Misc**, set the account as you would like.

Comment: Thanx, but the right answer is to check Environment.UserName in OnStart().